# Mailto does not invoke outlook in chrome.

Tags: c#, google-chrome, email, outlook, mailto

In view I rendered two links that have mailto. Both of them have body attributes passed to mailto. One has short body text, other very long. When I click on link that has shorter body, it works and outlook opens. Link with longer body does not work (I clicked and nothing happens). But that happens only in chrome. In other browsers both links work. I noticed that in Chrome page source longer body text is made shorter with some notation. This might be the issue.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I figured out, that my body is longer than 1024 symbols and that's why mailto does not invoke outlook. maybe someone knows how to extend maximum mailto body size ?

Answer (score 0):

Checking for spaces (and removing them) between the colon and the recipients, and between multiple recipients.

Variables that can be used with mailto:

**mailto:** set the recipient, or recipients, separate with comma

**&cc=** set the CC recipient(s)

**&bcc=** set the BCC recipient(s)

**&subject=** set the email subject, URL encode for longer sentences, so replace spaces with %20, etc.

**&body=** set the body of the message, including line breaks. Line breaks should be converted to %0A.

A MailTo Generator can be found [here](http://www.mailto.co.uk/).